# How to keep trailing zeros for decimal in AngularJS http response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to get a decimal value "as is" from DB. For instance, 1128.00398000000. I have sent a request using $http service as following:

```
let route = '/api/...';
let result = SimpleService.getData(route);
```

Then I use only successCallback function

```
result.then(
  function(response) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
  }
);
```

When I took a look at a response object, it contains 1128.00398 for the certain property, but if I open Network and verify what the back-end service actually returned in JSON - it is as it should be full-format.

Back-end service returns "PropertyName": 1128.00398000000 in JSON for that property.

That's just simple example.

It seems to me that AngularJS did a trick inside. What is it?

Comment: It probably parsed the passed string as a number.

Comment: @Cerbrus So, should I send such data in string format with quotes to avoid it? How to keep it as is?

Comment: That would be a solution, yes. If the value is a number in the JSON string, JavaScript will interpret it as a number, and drop the trailing zeros. If it's a string, it will take the value as-is.

Comment: If you need the trailing zeroes for display purposes then just format the number when displaying.

Comment: Hint: [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: It makes sense if I want all such values in a certain format, but I don't. The value could be 1.000000001 or even 1.000000000001 up to the maximum as it is in DB. @Cerbrus thanks for pointing out about parsing. That is a reason why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is a number in the JSON string, JavaScript will interpret it as a number, and drop the trailing zeros:

```js
let foo = JSON.parse('{"bar":123.45600000}');
console.log(foo.bar);
```

If it's a string, it will not interpret the value as a number, thus render the value as-is.

```js
let foo = JSON.parse('{"bar":"123.45600000"}');
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Comment: As we already discussed it in comments, that's correct and the answer. Accepting it.